# Trouble with java.io.IOException: Your default credentials were not found

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, credentials, api-key, google-secret-manager

I am trying to host an API key for openai on google cloud services as a secret, and then access the key via secret manager.
I am developing a app in android studio and have all of the functionality I want, even got the rewards ads working well.
I have the key stored and the necessary ID's: secret name, project id, version.
But whatever methods I try I get the same error and app crash when the app tries to make a call using the api key and I get the error " java.io.IOException: Your default credentials were not found".

I have tried this:

```
// Function to retrieve the secret
    fun getSecretValue(secretName: String): String {
        val client = SecretManagerServiceClient.create()
        val secretVersionName = SecretVersionName.of("SECRET ID", secretName, "1")
        val response = client.accessSecretVersion(secretVersionName)
        val secretValue = response.payload.data.toStringUtf8()
        client.close()
        return secretValue
    }
```

and this,

```
private fun getOpenAIApiKey(): String {
        // Initialize the Secret Manager client
        val client = SecretManagerServiceClient.create()

        // The name of the secret you created in Secret Manager
        val secretVersionName = SecretVersionName.of("PROJECT ID", "SECRET", "VERSION")

        return try {
            // Access the secret's value
            val response = client.accessSecretVersion(secretVersionName)
            val apiKey = response.payload.data.toStringUtf8()

            apiKey
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // Handle exceptions here, e.g., log the error or return a default value
            "default-api-key"
        } finally {
            // Close the client when done
            client.close()
        }
    }
```

all to no avail,

I understand the resource file named "google_cloud_credentials" is not found in the Android project's resources directory or it is not correctly referenced. But I am not really sure what to do about this or if I am taking the wrong approach altogether, I have been working on this app for months.. I have tried making a server account in the cloud as well and feeding in the secret and setting up a .json key but I am not sure I am setting that up right either since I get the same error after using,

```
 // Assuming your JSON key file is in res/raw/google_cloud_credentials.json
        val resourceId = R.raw.google_cloud_credentials
        val inputStream = applicationContext.resources.openRawResource(resourceId)

        try {
            // Create a temporary file to store the credentials
            val tempFile = File.createTempFile("google_cloud_credentials", ".json")

            // Copy the contents of the raw resource (JSON key) to the temporary file
            inputStream.use { input ->
                FileOutputStream(tempFile).use { output ->
                    input.copyTo(output)
                }
            }

            // Set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS property to the path of the temporary file
            System.setProperty("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", tempFile.absolutePath)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // Handle the exception
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

I have done tutorials on google cloud console on how to setup secret keys and access them but they are in python and I don't really see how it translates to what I am doing.

Any insight on this would mean a lot to me.

[EDIT]

I managed to get firebase storage to store an API KEY and successfully accessed the key after authenticating with google sign in/firebase. I set pretty lax rules on access to the database, but I am not sure whether google secrets manager is a more secure option at this point? Will update the question if I test google secrets manager now that I am authenticated to see if it works.